# R: Extracting charcters from string vectors to data frame rows

Tags: r, dataframe, substring

I have a data frame which has one colomn, a list of words. I'd like to extract the charcters from each word and have it stored as a position colomn in the data frame. For example, if the dataframe is defined like this:

```
words <- c('which', 'there', 'their', 'would') 
words <- as.data.frame(words)
```

I'd like it to look like this at the end:

| words | first_pos | second_pos | third_pos | fourth_pos | fifth_pos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| which | w | h | i | c | h |
| there | t | h | e | r | e |
| their | t | h | e | i | r |
| would | w | o | u | l | d |

What I have so far is:

```
position <- c("first_pos", "second_pos", "third_pos", "fourth_pos", "fifth_pos")
words[position] <- NA
dismantled <- str_split(words$words,"")
```

This dismantles the words and creates the colomns I need. However, I could use some help filling the rows of the colomns with the letters.

Comment: You need `words[position] <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, dismantled)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `separate` after a space between each character in `words`:

```
library(tidyverse)
words %>%
  mutate(words1 =  sub("\\s+$", "", gsub('(.{1})', '\\1 ', words))) %>% 
  separate(words1, into = paste0(1:5, "_pos"))
```

```
  words 1_pos 2_pos 3_pos 4_pos 5_pos
1 which     w     h     i     c     h
2 there     t     h     e     r     e
3 their     t     h     e     i     r
4 would     w     o     u     l     d
```